# How to access the Methods inside a class of a Project DLL in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, methods, dll

I have been learning C# and was trying to create a particular Logic in a separate Solution.

In this scenario, I created a Project with a few classes and each class has particular methods for certain processes. I have created a DLL for this Project, let's call it "LogicLibrary.DLL"

Now, I have created another Project where I added a reference to the "LogicLibrary.DLL".

Now, my problem is that I am not sure how I should access the methods inside the classes of the DLL.

Suppose LogicLibrary.DLL has a class "Calculator.cs" which in turn has methods `Add(int a, int b)`, `Sub(int a, int b)`, `Mul(int a, int b)` and `Div(int a, int b)`.

In the new project, how can I access any of the methods mentioned above. Is there any particular way of creating an object for the classes inside the DLL?

Would love your help!...Thank You!

Comment: Is `Calculator` a static class?  if not, you'll need to either instantiate the class or inherit from it.

Comment: You should not create a separate solution.  Be sure your access modifiers (public, internal, private..) are set correctly.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's probably a bad idea to directly reference DLL's from external solutions. Whenever possible, if you need to reference code from outside your solution, you should create NuGet packages and store them in a NuGet server. This allows you to manage version dependencies between one solution and the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have imported the library. Now you need to tell the compiler how to find the class you intend to use.

All libraries have a default namespace. You can see it by right-clicking on your project and selecting Properties.

Your class definition can also indicate a namespace. For instance:

```
namespace LogicLibrary
{
     //Class(es) here
}
```

So, if you import this library by adding a reference, your code to consume the class has to tell the compiler where to find it. You can do this in a few ways:

You can import the namespace so that it gets applied automatically by the compiler:

```
using LogicLibrary;
```

You can also fully qualify the name of the class you intend to use:

```
var calculator = new LogicLibrary.Calculator();
```

Either way works. Namespaces are nothing more than logical containers meant to help you organize the code to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

if you have added the LogicLibrary.dll in refrences, you only need to put this in usings.

```
using LogicLibrary;
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the project and then found that I can create an object of the class like this :

LogicLibrary.Calculator calculatorObject = new LogicLibrary.Calculator();
int sum = calculatorObject.Add(1,3);